# One python multiprocess errors

Tags: python, multiprocess

I have one multprocess demo here, and I met some problems with it. Researched for a night, I cannot resolve the reason.
Any one can help me?

I want to have one parent process acts as producer, when there are tasks come, the parent can fork some children to consume these tasks. The parent monitors the child, if any one exits with exception, it can be restarted by parent.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue from Queue import Empty import sys, signal, os, random, time import traceback

child_process = []
child_process_num = 4
queue = Queue(0)

def work(queue):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIG_DFL)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_DFL)

    time.sleep(10) #demo sleep 

def kill_child_processes(signum, frame):
    #terminate all children
    pass

def restart_child_process(signum, frame):
    global child_process

    for i in xrange(len(child_process)):
        child = child_process[i]

        try:
            if child.is_alive():
                continue
        except OSError, e:
            pass

        child.join() #join this process to make sure there is no zombie process

        new_child = Process(target=work, args=(queue,))
        new_child.start()
        child_process[i] = new_child #restart one new process

        child = None
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

    for i in xrange(child_process_num):
        child = Process(target=work, args=(queue,))
        child.start()
        child_process.append(child)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, kill_child_processes)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, kill_child_processes) #hook the SIGTERM
    signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, restart_child_process)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

When this program runs, there will be errors as below:

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/atexit.py", line 30, in _run_exitfuncs
    traceback.print_exc()
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/traceback.py", line 227, in print_exc
    print_exception(etype, value, tb, limit, file)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/traceback.py", line 124, in print_exception
    _print(file, 'Traceback (most recent call last):')
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/traceback.py", line 12, in _print
    def _print(file, str='', terminator='\n'):
  File "test.py", line 42, in restart_child_process
    new_child.start()
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in start
    _cleanup()
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 53, in _cleanup
    if p._popen.poll() is not None:
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 106, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

If I send signal to one child：kill –SIGINT {child_pid} I will get:

```
[root@mail1 mail]# kill -SIGINT 32545
[root@mail1 mail]# Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 269, in _exit_function
    p.join()
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 119, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 117, in wait
    return self.poll(0)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 106, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
OSError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 269, in _exit_function
    p.join()
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 119, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 117, in wait
    return self.poll(0)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 106, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
OSError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

Answer (score 1):

Main proc is waiting for all child procs to be terminated before exits itself so there's a blocking call (i.e. wait4) registered as at_exit handles. The signal you sent interrupts that blocking call thus the stack trace.

The thing I'm not clear about is that if the signal sent to child would be redirected to the parent process, which then interrupted that wait4 call. This is something related to the Unix process group behaviors.